# iTerm2 swap panes keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, iterm2, iterm

The option for swapping between panes is only available through the menu button but I can't see any action to bind to this action. Is there and in built command that allows to swap panes?

Comment: Thank you @solr for bringing the newer response to our attention. I will update the correct answer appropriately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correction for the second part of the selected answer:

> If you mean swapping the positions of the panes, it can only be done from the
> right-click menu:
>
> 1. Right-click pane to swap from, it turns red
> 2. Click on pane to swap to
>    There is no keyboard shortcut for this according to gitlab issue

**You can set it on your own.**
Go to iTerm2->Prefrences->Keys.
On the bottom you will find a plus sign - press it to add a keyboard shortcut.
You can choose from a variety of actions - including "**swap position with split screen**".

Comment: Upvoted, this is the answer OP was looking for.

Answer (score 59):

If you mean switching focus between panes:

```
⌘ + ⌥ + ← and ⌘ + ⌥ + →
```

or

```
⌘ + [ and ⌘ + ]
```

If you mean swapping the positions of the panes, it can only be done from the right-click menu:

1. Right-click pane to swap from, it turns red
2. Click on pane to swap to

There is no keyboard shortcut for this according to [gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/1691)

Comment: I mean the last one. Keyboard shortcut for dragging the pane to new position. Would be nice feature to have

Comment: swap pane with other session is what I was looking for, thank you. switch positions of existing split panes.

Comment: @chrisxrobertson thanks was looking for this for awhile.